# String coming from DB as \\xC3\\xB6 but I need the actual character "ö" to write to CSV

Tags: ruby, unicode, encoding, utf-8, yaml

I'm reading a YAML string from a database I have no control over which has unicode stored as string literals.

I'd like to output the actual character `ö` in a csv file but it's still putting out `\\xC3\\xB6`

Help.

Comment: What do you mean by _"unicode stored as string literals"_? Does the file contain the characters ``\``, `x`, `C` and `3`?

Comment: The row in the DB literally contains the text `"\\xc3\\xb6"`
EDIT: When I pull it out the DB, that's what it looks like in Ruby

Comment: Are that 8 characters? ``\``, `x`, `C`, `3`, ``\``, `x`, `B`, `6`

Comment: That is correct @Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database apparently contains malformed strings. Since you can't fix the bug at its source (i.e. within the database), you could use `gsub` to replace each hex escape sequence with its actual value:

```
str = "\\xc3\\xb6"
#=> "\\xc3\\xb6"
str.length
#=> 8

str.gsub!(/\\x(\h{2})/) { [$1].pack('H2') }
#=> "\xC3\xB6"
str.length
#=> 2
```

You can then tell Ruby to interpret the string's bytes as UTF-8:

```
str.force_encoding('UTF-8')
#=> "ö"
str.length
#=> 1
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks.

Comment: @DonatelloTallfeather if you're uncomfortable with `pack`, you can also use `$1.to_i(16).chr` for the conversion.